# Possible to create Nested Table with data from 2 different Lists?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have a custom object related to Account via look up relationship. For each of the custom object records I would like to display the related AccountHistory.

In theory, I would ideally like to pull 2 lists, Custom Record list and Account history list and then display the records as nested pageblocktable.

Since these 2 objects are not exactly related I am wondering if this is even possible in visual force?

**Update**

```
public Class Engagement {


  public Engagement__c[] getDelta(){

   List<Engagement__c> x = [SELECT Name, ID,CreatedDate,Account_ID__c,Delta__c,Account_Name__c,
                      FROM Engagement__c  
                      WHERE (CreatedDate2EqualsToday_1__c = TRUE)
                      ORDER BY Account_ID__c,CreatedDate ASC];

    if(!x.isEmpty())
   {
   for(Integer i=1; i<x.size();i++)
    {
        if(x[i].Account_ID__c == x[i-1].Account_ID__c)
        {
             x[i].Delta__c = x[i].Engagement_Score__c-x[i-1].Engagement_Score__c;                                              
          i++;            
        }     
        else system.debug('nothing found');
    }
    }
  return x;
  }

 Map<id,AccountHistory> mapAccountHistory = new Map<id,AccountHistory>(); 
}
```

I need to Link result from getDelta() to AccountHistory by using the Account ID field that exists in Engagement__c. I have never used MAPs before so I am really struggling here.

Comment: Did you try anything at your end, if so post your code

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have a custom object, let's say, `MyObject__c` which has a lookup to `Account`, let's say, `Account__c`. `AccountHistory` object has `AccountId` field which you can use to map custom records and account history records based on the value in `Account__c`. You can write a custom Visualforce page + controller to display custom object records with nested `AccountHistory` records based on the value in `Account__c` on custom object record.

And, your question 'Since these 2 objects are not exactly related I am wondering if this is even possible in visual force?', it is possible, however, you will need custom Apex code, setup and fill data structure in controller and use couple of `apex:repeat` or `pageBlockTable` components to render nested tables.

I have just put together as idea that you may want to proceed with.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Does it have be a nested SOQL query or it can be 2 separate lists?

Comment: I think a list of custom object records and a map of account history records with account ids as map keys.